# Unable to figure out regex pattern

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, .net-2.0

I have a string with some custom formula like `FVAL("A")+FVAL(B)`. I want to figure out all string inside `FVAL()` which does not have quotes around it.

So basically I want to extract out `B` because it does not have quotes around it.

Comment: what happens when you have FVAL(ABC+"B")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
FVAL\(([^")]*)\)
```

This matches `FVAL(`, followed by any number of characters except quotes or closing parentheses, followed by `)`.

Another possibility (where the match would be in `$0` instead of `$1`:

```
(?<=FVAL\()[^")]*(?=\))
```

This matches a non-quote/non-parenthesis-string that is surrounded by `FVAL(` and `)`.

In VB.net:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("FVAL\(([^"")]*)\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim MatchResult As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
While MatchResult.Success
    ResultList.Add(MatchResult.Groups(1).Value)
    MatchResult = MatchResult.NextMatch()
End While
```

or

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("(?<=FVAL\()[^"")]*(?=\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim MatchResult As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
While MatchResult.Success
    ResultList.Add(MatchResult.Value)
    MatchResult = MatchResult.NextMatch()
End While
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked great. But what if I have something like `MVAL("A","01-01-1900")`. How I would only extract the first parameter?

Comment: You should create a new question for this since it's a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want an expression something like

```
"FVAL\\(([^\"]+)\\)"
```

which includes a set of parentheses for the capture group.

Comment: Not working. Its not finding any match in the string `FVAL("A")+FVAL(B)`. The regex ismatch function is returing false. 
`Regex.IsMatch(vbCode, "FVAL\([^""](.+?)[^""]\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`